# How often can I ask a question?

Tags: discussion, asking-questions, rate-limiting

I wonder what is the time limit of how often can one ask a question on Math Stack Exchange?

I tried to ask a new question shortly after I posted one, and the Ask Question link always referred me back to the old question.

Sincere thanks!

Comment: [Somewhat coincidentally...](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/168456)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There are several limits on the number of questions you can ask, the hard limits are 6 questions per day and 50 questions per month.

As a new user there are some additional rate limits to prevent abuse, [any user below 125 reputation can only ask a question every 20 minutes](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/164899/the-complete-rate-limiting-guide). A high reputation user can post questions pretty quickly until they hit one of the rate limits I mentioned above.

In general, *everything* on SE sites is rate-limited in some way to prevent abuse. Even moderators writing moderator messages or suspending users are rate-limited, and as far as I know those limits also apply to SE employees using those tools.

Comment: "...there are some additional rate limits to prevent abuse, those are not documented exactly as far as I know." - security through obscurity? :)

Comment: @J.M. They are actually documented now on MSO, though I'm not sure if that list is really complete.

Comment: Employees not including those who maintain the database and can actually screw with you through there, though. :-)