# Etiquette about posting a large number of questions about preliminary exams.

Tags: discussion, soft-question

I am Currently studying for my preliminary exams (Advanced Calculus and Linear Algebra), and I can solve about half of the previous years exam questions. However, I do not have anyone to vet my proofs at the moment. My question is it appropriate to ask a large number of questions on here?

Comment: Sort of depends on what "large" means. Also, I would say it's probably not a good idea to ask 20 questions in 1 minute, but if you ask one question at a time and are responsive when you get answers, then I see no reason to ask several questions.

Comment: I only plan to ask questions as I go along. I will try to solve all of the problems I ask, and give my thoughts on the problem.  However, my exams are five months away, so it is possible that I have trouble with several problems before then.

Comment: You will find that you cannot ask too too many --- the system limits the number of questions you can ask per time period - 6 per day, 50 per month. Further, other users or mods will mention something if they think you've done something out of line. Really, if you ask good quality questions in good faith, I think you'll get along just fine.

Comment: you may also search if a similar question (to the ones you will be posting) has already been posted

Comment: I would hope that rather than asking a whole lot of questions all at once you will ask one question, see whether the answers you get help you to answer some of your other questions, then ask one more question, etc.

Comment: By large I mean no more than 3 a day or so. I just have seen questions on here with little to no effort that are clearly on homework, and it is frustrating.

Answer (score 12):

Well, to start with the facts, [users are limited](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9162/how-often-can-i-ask-a-question/9164#9164) to asking 50 questions in a month or 6 questions in a day. Aside from that, provided that your questions are of good quality (and remain well received by the community), it's acceptable to post as many as you wish.

From your comment about vetting proofs, it might be worth having a look at [this meta thread](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19881/) discussing how to ask proof-verification questions well. The more specific you can be the better - a question which asks, "Is this step legal?" is more likely to give you a helpful answer than simply "Look at this proof."